# Custom annotation on controller methods to intercept request and validate

Tags: spring, spring-boot, annotations, httprequest

I want to create an annotation that I will use on controller methods to validate access to the resource. I have written interceptor to intercept the request and also written code to create an annotation for their independent scenarios. Now I want intercept the request as well as take values provided in anotation to further processing.

Ideally

```
@RequestMapping("/release")
@ValidateAction("resource","release") //custom annotation that will accept two strings
public ResponseEntity releaseSoftware(Request request){
}
```

From the above I have to take those two values from @ValidateAction and send a request to another authorization server to authorize the action if the user have access to it (request contains oauth access token that will be used to authorize) and return true if the user have access otherwise throw AcceeDenied exception.
Can anybody point me in the right direction of doing it in Spring boot environment

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Best way to achieve this is using Spring AOP Aspects.

Let us assume you have an Annotation like this

```
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface ValidateAction {

  String resource();
  String release();
}
```

Then write an Aspect like this

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class AspectClass {

  @Around(" @annotation(com.yourpackage.ValidateAction)")
  public Object validateAspect(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
    MethodSignature signature = (MethodSignature) pjp.getSignature();
    Method method = signature.getMethod();

    ValidateAction validateAction = method.getAnnotation(ValidateAction.class);
    String release = validateAction.release();
    String resource = validateAction.resource();


    // Call your Authorization server and check if all is good
    if( hasAccess)
      pjp.proceed();

    .......
  }
}
```

Control will come to validateAspect method when any method which is annotated with `@ValidateAction` is called. Here you capture the annotation values as shown and do the necessary check.

Make sure you have the right dependency needed and these imports

```
import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.reflect.MethodSignature;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
```

Comment: I wasted my whole Saturday before find your post, my point cut not work following almost of guides, I don't known why:
@Around(value = "@annotation(annotate)", argNames = "joinPoint,annotate")
public Object handle(final ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint, SequenceNext annotate)

Answer (score 4):

You can do it with `Spring AOP`:

First, add `spring-aop` dependency:

```
compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop' // Mine using gradle
```

In your `@Configuration` class, add `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy`:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
public class Application {
   ....
}
```

Create an annotation handler:

```
@Aspect
@Component // This @Component is required in spring aop
public class ValidateActionHandler {
    @Around("execution(@your.path.ValidateAction * *(..)) && @annotation(validateAction)")
    public Object doValidate(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp, ValidateAction retryConfig) throws Throwable {
       // Your logic here
       // then
       return pjp.proceed();
    }
}
```